# Will Angular 2.0 understand Polymers shadow DOM?

Tags: angular, polymer

In preparation for angular 2.0 I am using polymer. Does anyone know if the current polymer implementation is ready so that Angular 2.0 will be able to receive updates from polymer components/models. Currently only polymer can listen to angular model updates.

I would like my current UI to be ready for angular 2.0 ideally without having to modify the polymer code too much.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is actually yes, as per the [answer of Miško Hevery at a ngEurope conference's Q&A a couple of days ago](http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/267/my-thoughts-on-ngeurope-2014-and-angularjs-2-0#attachment_275). And this makes sense in the context of Angular 2.0 embracing Web Components.

Answer (score 1):

There is no mention of it in the 2.0 roadmap (http://angularjs.blogspot.se/2014/03/angular-20.html) however it is mentioned in the ideas design doc (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tSrXqMiFd8lAdTkp78Do-6V5nNjQ8b2P01AlYG9FOWQ/edit).

I've seen a couple of presentations (i.e. https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1Gv-dvU-yy6WY7SiNJ9QRo9XayPS6N2jtgWezdRpoI04/present#slide=id.g108668b30_071) that mention shadow dom in Angular's "future" but doesn't specify when.

Probably the best answer is Angular 2.0 is still in design phase and not coming out soon enough to start worrying about it.